# Estimate a model that predicts the probability of purchasing Coke (Coke==1) as a function of price ratio and display (both Coke and Pepsi)

Tags: r, statistics, probability, rscript

[image]

Dataset coke.dta contains the choice between Coke and Pepsi by 1140 shoppers from scanner data. The variable pratio represents the relative price of Coke compared to Pepsi—for example, if pratio=1.1, it indicates that the price of Coke was 10% higher than that of Pepsi. Disp_Coke and disp_pepsi are indicator variables if the product was on special display at the time of the purchase.

(a) Estimate a model that predicts the probability of purchasing Coke (Coke==1) as a function of price ratio and display (both Coke and Pepsi).

What kind of R function do i use to make this kind of model? (the picture is just to show how the dataset looks)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking here seems dramatically outside the scope of a simple stackoverflow question.

The answer to your question is almost certainly the function ***lm*** from the ***stats*** package which will perform linear regression on your dataset, but knowing whether it is or not is an entire process of data analysis itself.

I recommend reading this article on performing linear regression modeling in R http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html

It can walk you through the basic steps of linear regression modeling far better than I can here, and there is a link at the bottom to another article that discusses the besic assumptions required for linear regression modeling to be an appropriate choice for your data.

Edit: I decieded to just link that article here too: http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html